# Resize svg icon using path element

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using a predesigned menu which has been used `svg` for drawing icons.

For some reasons, I have to change icon size using **`path`** element.

Now, I want to change icon and I have my own custom icons; So, I downloaded some `svg` icon of web, **BUT** icons which has been used by me, have the same size that they had, even if I use large svg icons made by [material design icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/).

This is my Original path element:

```
<path class="Shape" d="M4.7 29.3a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.7zM4.4 8a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0 7.3H4.4zm0 42a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.4z"/>
```

**And this is my svg structure:**

```html
       <svg class="menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 792 792">
        <defs>
            <path class="path-1" d="M45 67.9c0 2.3 1.9 4.1 4.2 4.1a4.1 4.1 0 1 0 0-8.3 4.1 4.1 0 0 0-4.1 4.2zm6 0c0 1-.8 1.7-1.8 1.7s-1.8-.7-1.8-1.7.8-1.8 1.8-1.8 1.8.7 1.8 1.8z"/>
        </defs>
        <g class="All-on" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-571 -143)">
            <g class="menu" transform="translate(571 143)">
                <g class="outside-layer">
                    <circle class="outer-cirlce-background" cx="396" cy="396" r="396" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".4"/>
                    <g class="more-menu" transform="translate(654 229)">
                        <g class="writing-button" transform="translate(24 120)">
                            <title>My Posts</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-11" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M66.7 53.6l-.3.5-1.3 1.8-.3.4-.1.3V60l-.2.3v.1c-.3 1-1 1.4-2.3 1.4h-4.5l-.6.1a9 9 0 0 0-4 1.6l-1.7 1.1-.5.4-1.5 1a302.7 302.7 0 0 0-4 2.6c-.2 0-.3-.1-.5-.3L41.5 66l-1.7-1-.4-.4a141.7 141.7 0 0 1-3-1.8 9 9 0 0 0-2.6-.9h-.1a15.6 15.6 0 0 0-1.4 0h-3.7c-1.2 0-2-.6-2.3-1.5v-.1l-.1-.3V39c0-1.8.7-2.6 2.5-2.6h27.5l.7-2.1H28.7C25.8 34.3 24 36 24 39v21l.1.4a4.5 4.5 0 0 0 .4 1.4v.2l.4.5.2.1c0 .2.2.3.3.4l.2.2a3.4 3.4 0 0 0 .7.4 3.2 3.2 0 0 0 .8.3l.5.1.5.1h4.2l1 .1h.2a7.3 7.3 0 0 1 2.7 1l.3.2.9.6 2.6 1.7v.1l3.7 2.5a3 3 0 0 0 1.7.5 3 3 0 0 0 1.7-.5l3.6-2.5h.1l2.6-1.8 1-.6.2-.2.6-.3c.7-.4 1.4-.6 2.1-.7h5l.3-.1h.6l.5-.2h.3l.5-.3a2.8 2.8 0 0 0 .7-.4 5.3 5.3 0 0 0 .5-.6 3.9 3.9 0 0 0 .8-1.4l.2-.8v-6.9.1z"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M70 25.6l-4-1.2a3 3 0 0 0-1.9 0c-.9.3-1.6 1.1-2 2.1l-.4 1.4-.2.5-.2.7-6.7 20.6.1 8.5v.2c.3.8.7 1.4 1.4 1.7.5.3 1.2.4 1.8.1.4-.1.8-.4 1.2-.8 1.2-1.5 2.4-3 3.4-4.6l1.6-2.3.1-.1 6.3-19.2.6-1.6.6-1.8c.6-1.9-.2-3.6-1.8-4.2zM56.3 50l6.4-19.5.6.2.7.3-6.3 19.3c-.6.2-1 .2-1.4 0V50zm4.1 1.4c-1.5.2-2-.6-2.1-.8l6.3-19.4 2.3.8-6.5 19.4zm.9 2.4a62 62 0 0 1-3 4l-1.9-.7v-6l1.4-.1c.3.5 1 1.2 2.7 1 .1.4.5.8 1.4.9l-.6 1zm1.5-2.2l-.4.6c-1 0-1.3-.3-1.4-.5l6.5-19.5 1.5.5-6.2 19zm7.4-22.4l-.6 1.9-5.8-2-.6-.1.2-.6.4-1.3c.3-1 1-1.4 1.8-1.2l3.8 1.3c.8.3 1.1 1.1.8 2z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="new-button">
                            <title>New Posts</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-13" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M46.1 46.5H36c-.4 0-.8.3-.8.8v1.5c0 .4.4.7.8.7h10.1c.2 0 .4.2.4.4V60c0 .4.3.8.8.8h1.5c.4 0 .7-.4.7-.8V49.9c0-.2.2-.4.4-.4H60c.4 0 .8-.3.8-.8v-1.5c0-.4-.4-.7-.8-.7H49.9a.4.4 0 0 1-.4-.4V36c0-.4-.3-.8-.8-.8h-1.5c-.4 0-.7.4-.7.8v10.1c0 .2-.2.4-.4.4z"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M48 69a21 21 0 1 0 0-42 21 21 0 0 0 0 42zm0 3a24 24 0 1 1 0-48 24 24 0 0 1 0 48z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="bin-button" transform="translate(0 240)">
                            <title>Deleted Posts</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-12" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M57 28v-3.8H39.2V28h-10v8.2h4.4v35.5h29V36.3h4.3V28H57zm-15.7-1.8h13.6v1.9H41.3v-1.9zm19.2 43.6H35.7V36.3h24.8v33.5zM65 34.2H31.3v-4H65v4z"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M41 42.7h2v20.7h-2zm6.1 0h2v20.7h-2zm6.1 0h2.1v20.7h-2.1z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="home-menu" transform="translate(229 18)">
                        <g class="portfolio-button" transform="translate(119)">
                            <title>Portfolio</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-4" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M71.6 46v-5.6c0-3.5-2.9-6.4-6.4-6.4h-7l-1-3.5c-.6-1.8-2.3-3-4.1-3H42.9a4.3 4.3 0 0 0-4 3L37.8 34h-7a6.4 6.4 0 0 0-6.4 6.4V46c0 .5.3.9.7 1l1 .4v15.5c0 3.5 2.8 6.4 6.4 6.4h31c3.6 0 6.5-2.9 6.5-6.4V47.3l1-.4c.3-.1.6-.5.6-1zM40.9 31c.3-.9 1.1-1.5 2-1.5h10.2c.9 0 1.7.6 2 1.5l.9 3H40l1-3zm-14.3 9.3c0-2.3 1.9-4.2 4.2-4.2h34.4a4.3 4.3 0 0 1 4.2 4.2v4.8L48 53.5l-21.4-8.3v-4.8zm41.2 22.4a4.3 4.3 0 0 1-4.2 4.3H32.4c-2.3 0-4.2-2-4.2-4.3V48l19.4 7.5h.8L67.8 48v14.7z"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M52.5 45a4.5 4.5 0 1 0-9 0 4.5 4.5 0 0 0 9 0zm-6.8 0a2.3 2.3 0 1 1 2.3 2.3c-1.3 0-2.3-1-2.3-2.4z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="testimonials-button" transform="translate(0 23)">
                            <title>Testimonials</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-6" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M52.9 64.6c-.7 0-1.3-.1-1.8-.5-.5-.3-1.2-1-1.1-2.5 0-2 1.7-3 2.9-3.6l.4-.2c1.6-1 2.8-1.7 3.8-2.6 2-1.7 3-3.2 2.9-3.6l-.3-.1-1.1-.2-1-.1a8.9 8.9 0 0 1-7.7-9.1 10.8 10.8 0 0 1 21.6 0c0 7-3.6 16.9-13.7 21.1l-.3.1c-1.1.5-3 1.3-4.6 1.3zm7.8-31.3c-4.8 0-8.8 4-8.8 8.8 0 3.8 2.2 6.5 6 7.2h.8l1.6.3c1.2.4 1.5 1.2 1.6 1.7.3 1.8-2 4.2-3.6 5.4-1 1-2.4 1.8-4 2.8l-.5.2c-1.2.6-1.9 1-1.9 1.9 0 .5.1.8.3.9.6.4 2.1 0 4.6-1l.2-.1a20.8 20.8 0 0 0 12.6-19.3c0-5-4-8.8-8.9-8.8zM27.4 64.6c-.7 0-1.3-.1-1.8-.5-.5-.3-1.2-1-1.1-2.5 0-2 1.7-3 2.9-3.6l.4-.2c1.6-1 2.8-1.7 3.8-2.6 2-1.7 3-3.2 2.9-3.6l-.3-.1-1.1-.2-1-.1a8.9 8.9 0 0 1-7.6-9.1 10.8 10.8 0 0 1 21.5 0 23 23 0 0 1-13.7 21.1l-.2.1c-1.2.5-3 1.3-4.7 1.3zm7.8-31.3c-4.8 0-8.8 4-8.8 8.8 0 3.8 2.2 6.5 6 7.2h.8l1.6.3c1.2.4 1.5 1.2 1.6 1.7.4 1.8-2 4.2-3.5 5.4-1.2 1-2.5 1.8-4.2 2.8l-.4.2c-1.1.6-1.9 1-1.9 1.9 0 .5.1.8.3.9.9.6 3.7-.6 4.6-1l.2-.1a20.8 20.8 0 0 0 12.6-19.3c0-5-3.9-8.8-8.9-8.8z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="contact-button" transform="translate(239 23)">\
                            <title>Contact Us</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-5" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M40.4 42.7c1.4 0 1.4 2 0 2H29.1L36 56.3l7-7c1.1-1 2.5.4 1.6 1.4L37 58.2l3.4 6h21.5a290 290 0 0 0-6.5-10c-.7-1.3 1-2.4 1.8-1.2l2.5 3.8h9l-.4-4.7H57.9c-1.4 0-1.4-2 0-2h10.2l-.4-5.4h-5.8c-1.4 0-1.4-2 0-2h6.7c.6 0 1.1.3 1.1 1 .6 7 1.6 14.5 1.9 21.4a1 1 0 0 1-1.1 1H25.4a1 1 0 0 1-1-1l1.9-21.5c0-.4.5-1 1.1-1h13zM28.2 47l-1.6 17H38l-9.7-17zm36 17h5.2l-.5-5.3h-8l3.3 5.4zm-14-9.2c-2.7-3.3-8.7-11.7-8.7-16.1 0-5.4 4.4-9.4 9.6-9.4 5.1 0 9.7 4 9.7 9.4 0 4.4-6.1 12.8-9 16.1-.3.6-1 .5-1.5 0zm.9-2.2c2.3-2.8 7.5-10.5 7.5-14 0-4.2-3.5-7.1-7.5-7.1s-7.4 3-7.4 7.2c0 3.4 5.2 11.1 7.4 14zm0-19c2.3 0 4.2 2 4.2 4.3 0 2.2-1.9 4-4.2 4a4.1 4.1 0 0 1 0-8.2zm0 2.1c-1.1 0-2 1-2 2.2 0 1 .9 2 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2.1-2c0-1.3-.9-2.2-2.1-2.2z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="settings-menu" transform="translate(228 654)">
                        <g class="security-button" transform="translate(120 24)">
                            <title>Secuirty Settings</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-8" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M48.2 64.6c.5 0 1-.5 1-1v-4.8A4 4 0 0 0 48 51a4 4 0 0 0-.9 8v4.6c0 .6.5 1 1 1zM46 55a2 2 0 1 1 3.9 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zm19.2-3.1c.5 0 1-.5 1-1v-4c0-2.2-1.9-4-4.2-4h-3.3v-8.3a10.6 10.6 0 0 0-21.3 0v8.2h-3.3A4.2 4.2 0 0 0 30 47v20.4c0 2.3 1.9 4.2 4.2 4.2h28c2.2 0 4.1-1.9 4.1-4.2V57.3a1 1 0 1 0-2 0v10.1c0 1.2-1 2.1-2.2 2.1h-28a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V47a2 2 0 0 1 2-2.1h28a2 2 0 0 1 2.1 2v4c0 .5.5 1 1 1zm-8.6-9h-17v-8.3a8.5 8.5 0 0 1 17 0v8.2z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="profile-button">
                            <title>Profile Settings</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-9" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M60.7 46.5a14.9 14.9 0 1 0-25.6 0A21.7 21.7 0 0 0 26.3 64v3.3c0 2.3 1.9 4.2 4.2 4.2h34.8c2.3 0 4.2-1.9 4.2-4.2V64c0-6.9-3.3-13.3-8.8-17.4zM48 26.4a12.6 12.6 0 0 1 10.3 19.8A12.6 12.6 0 1 1 48 26.4zm19.2 40.8c0 1-.8 1.8-1.8 1.8H30.6c-1 0-1.9-.8-1.9-1.8v-3.3c0-6.1 3-11.8 7.8-15.5a15 15 0 0 0 11.4 5.4c4.5 0 8.6-2 11.5-5.4A19 19 0 0 1 67 64v3.3z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="contact-button" transform="translate(240)">
                            <title>Contact Settings</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-10" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M56.5 71.5L40 58.2h-9.4c-3 0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4v-23c0-3 2.4-5.3 5.4-5.3h34.1c3 0 5.4 2.4 5.4 5.3v23c0 3-2.4 5.4-5.3 5.4h-8.2v13.3zm-26.7-45c-2 .2-3 2.2-3 3.1v23.2c0 2.1 1 3.3 3 3.6h10.7l14.9 12.4V56.4H65c.8 0 3 .4 3-2.8 0-3.2.3-22 0-24-.2-2 0-3-3-3s-33.1-.2-35.2 0z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                    <g class="faq-menu" transform="translate(18 229)">
                        <g class="writing-button" transform="translate(0 120)">
                            <title>Writing FAQs</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-7" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M69.2 26.8a8.6 8.6 0 0 0-12.1 0L29.1 55h-.2v.2l-.1.2v.1l-.1.2L24.4 70c-.1.4 0 1 .4 1.4.3.2.6.4 1 .4h.4l14.3-4.3h.2l.2-.2h.1l.1-.1h.1l28-28.2a8.6 8.6 0 0 0 0-12.2zM27.9 68.1l2.8-9.6 6.7 6.7-9.5 3zm12.2-4L32 55.8l24-24 8 8.2-24 24zm27-27.2l-1 1-8.1-8 1-1a5.7 5.7 0 0 1 8.1 0 5.6 5.6 0 0 1 0 8z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="reading-button" transform="translate(24)">
                            <title>Reading FAQs</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-7" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M71.6 70.7h-2.9V37.9h-9v-9.6H27.5v42.4h-2.9V25.4h38V35h9z"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M69.4 36.9l-8.9-9.5 2.1-2 9 9.6zm-34.1 4.6h12.1v2.9H35.3zm0 11.7h25.5v3H35.3zm0 7.2h25.5v2.9H35.3z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="general-button" transform="translate(24 240)">
                            <title>General FAQs</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-7" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M54.3 68h-4V40.5a2 2 0 0 0-2-2h-6a2 2 0 1 0 0 4h4V68h-4a2 2 0 1 0 0 4h12a2 2 0 1 0 0-4zm-7.8-36a3.8 3.8 0 1 0 0-7.6 3.8 3.8 0 0 0 0 7.6z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g class="middle-layer" transform="translate(132 132)">
                    <circle class="middle-circle-backgroud" cx="264" cy="264" r="264" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".4"/>
                    <g class="button-group">
                        <g class="settings-button" transform="translate(216 408)">
                            <title>Settings Menu</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-3" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#F06" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M49.4 30.5a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0 12.2v24.6a1.4 1.4 0 0 1-2.8 0V42.7a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0-12.2V29a1.4 1.4 0 0 1 2.8 0v1.6zm-4.8 6.1a3.4 3.4 0 1 0 6.8 0 3.4 3.4 0 0 0-6.8 0zm-12.4 17a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0 12.1v1.6a1.4 1.4 0 0 1-3 0v-1.6a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0-12.1V28.9a1.4 1.4 0 0 1 3 0v24.7zm-4.8 6a3.4 3.4 0 1 0 6.7 0 3.4 3.4 0 0 0-6.7 0zM66.7 45a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0 12v10.3a1.4 1.4 0 0 1-2.9 0V57.1a6.2 6.2 0 0 1 0-12.2V29a1.4 1.4 0 0 1 3 0v16zM62 51a3.4 3.4 0 1 0 6.7 0 3.4 3.4 0 0 0-6.7 0z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="faq-button" transform="translate(24 217)">
                            <title>FAQ Menu</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#F06" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" stroke="#fff" d="M36.5 38.8c.6 0 1.2-.5 1.2-1.2a11 11 0 0 1 11.8-11 11 11 0 0 1 10 11.3c-.1 5.2-3.8 9.7-8.9 10.5a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-2.6 3.4v6a1.2 1.2 0 0 0 2.4 0v-6c0-1 .5-1 .7-1a13 13 0 0 0 10.8-12.9 13.3 13.3 0 1 0-26.6-.3c0 .7.5 1.2 1.2 1.2z"/>
                            <g class="Shape" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                <use fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd" xlink:href="#path-1"/>
                                <path stroke="#fff" d="M45.6 67.9a3.6 3.6 0 1 0 7.3 0c0-2-1.7-3.7-3.7-3.7s-3.6 1.6-3.6 3.7zm5.9 0c0 1.2-1 2.2-2.3 2.2-1.3 0-2.3-1-2.3-2.2 0-1.3 1-2.3 2.3-2.3 1.3 0 2.3 1 2.3 2.3z"/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                        <g class="home-button" transform="translate(216 24)">
                            <title>Home Menu</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-2" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#F06" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M64.2 46.8c-.7 0-1.3.6-1.3 1.3v20.7h-7.3v-8a7.1 7.1 0 0 0-14.3 0v8H34V48.1a1.3 1.3 0 0 0-2.7 0v22c0 .8.6 1.4 1.4 1.4h10c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3v-9.3a4.5 4.5 0 0 1 9 0v9.3c0 .7.5 1.3 1.2 1.3h10c.7 0 1.3-.6 1.3-1.3v-22c0-.8-.6-1.4-1.3-1.4zm6-1.2L49.3 25c-.5-.5-1.4-.5-2 0L26.8 45.6a1.3 1.3 0 1 0 2 2l19.7-19.9 19.9 19.8a1.3 1.3 0 1 0 1.8-1.9z"/>
                        </g>
                        <g class="more-button" transform="translate(408 217)">
                            <title>More Menu</title>
                            <circle class="Oval-2" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#F06" opacity=".6"/>
                            <path class="Shape" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M29.8 42a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-5.8 5.8c0 3.2 2.6 5.9 5.8 5.9 3.2 0 5.9-2.7 5.9-5.9S33 42 29.8 42zM48 42a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-5.8 5.8c0 3.2 2.6 5.9 5.8 5.9A5.9 5.9 0 1 0 48 42zm18.2 0a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-5.9 5.8c0 3.2 2.7 5.9 5.9 5.9S72 51 72 47.8 69.4 42 66.2 42zm-36.4 2.6c1.8 0 3.3 1.4 3.3 3.2 0 1.8-1.5 3.3-3.3 3.3a3.2 3.2 0 0 1-3.2-3.3c0-1.8 1.4-3.2 3.2-3.2zm18.2 0c1.8 0 3.2 1.4 3.2 3.2 0 1.8-1.4 3.3-3.2 3.3a3.2 3.2 0 0 1-3.2-3.3c0-1.8 1.4-3.2 3.2-3.2zm18.2 0c1.8 0 3.2 1.4 3.2 3.2 0 1.8-1.4 3.3-3.2 3.3a3.2 3.2 0 0 1-3.3-3.3c0-1.8 1.5-3.2 3.3-3.2z"/>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g class="main-menu" transform="translate(276 276)">
                    <title>Main Menu</title>
                    <circle class="inner-circle-background" cx="120" cy="120" r="120" fill="#000" opacity=".4"/>
                    <g class="menu-button" fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(84 95)">
                        {{--<path class="Shape" d="M4.7 29.3a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.7zM4.4 8a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0 7.3H4.4zm0 42a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.4z"/>--}}
                        <path class="Shape" d="M17.9,17.39C17.64,16.59 16.89,16 16,16H15V13A1,1 0 0,0 14,12H8V10H10A1,1 0 0,0 11,9V7H13A2,2 0 0,0 15,5V4.59C17.93,5.77 20,8.64 20,12C20,14.08 19.2,15.97 17.9,17.39M11,19.93C7.05,19.44 4,16.08 4,12C4,11.38 4.08,10.78 4.21,10.21L9,15V16A2,2 0 0,0 11,18M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z" />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I'm completely newbie to use svg, is there any way that I can use my custom icon with custom size just using ***`path`*** element?

Comment: All `path` data (`d` attribute) in an SVG is relative to the viewBox dimensions established on the outer `svg` element, `viewBox="0 0 792 792"` in this case. The `d` attribute gives coordinates relative to the 792x792 space. As you can imagine this is not easy to come up with the correct path data for a new icon in this case, mainly because the implementation trying to get all these icons to live in the same viewBox. More common approach is to make each icon its own `svg` element each with its own viewBox, and then use CSS to position them all relative to each other in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Next I'm using your original path element instead of the icon already there. You can use any icon you want and of any size if you put it inside a `<symbol>` element.

How did I do it: the `<symbol>` element has a `viewBox="0 -11 72 72"` Please note that the symbol is a square pf 72/72 units.

When you use a symbol you can give the `<use>` element a `x` and a `y` attributes to position the icon where you need.  You also can give the `<use>` element a `width` and a `height` attributes to size it to your needs.

In order to get the value for the `<symbol>` element you may use the `.getBBox()` method for the content of the symbol. In this case I did: `Shape.getBBox()`. I hope it helps.

```
 <use xlink:href="#test" x="28" y="28" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
```

```html
<svg class="menu" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 792 792">
    <defs>
      
     <symbol id="test" viewBox="0 -11 72 72">
  <path id="Shape" d="M4.7 29.3a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.7zM4.4 8a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0 7.3H4.4zm0 42a3.7 3.7 0 0 1 0-7.3h63.2a3.7 3.7 0 1 1 0 7.3H4.4z"/>
  </symbol>
      
    </defs>
    <g class="All-on" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-571 -143)">
    <g class="menu" transform="translate(571 143)">
    <g class="outside-layer">
    <circle class="outer-cirlce-background" cx="396" cy="396" r="396" fill="#000" fill-opacity=".4"/>
    <g class="more-menu" transform="translate(654 229)">
      
    <g class="writing-button" transform="translate(24 120)">
    <title>My Posts</title>
    <circle class="Oval-2-Copy-11" cx="48" cy="48" r="48" fill="#00F7FF" opacity=".6"/>
                        
                      
    <use xlink:href="#test" x="28" y="28" width="40" height="40" fill="white" />
                      
    </g>
      
    </g>
    </g>
    </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```